# How to set props of original component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope I'm making sense. I am trying to implement a MathLive component in react. There is a react-mathlive library however I believe that it is outdated and to use it I would need to install an older version of math live. https://github.com/concludio/react-mathlive/issues/34

I have been trying to implement a solution for hours and I was never able to get anything to work. All that I want to do is add an onChange attribute to a `<math-field>` "component". The `<math-field>` is not an actual react component but an actual html element. I have read the math live docs and to detect change all you need to do is set the onChange attribute. However, this does nothing when added directly into the react compoment. `<math-field onChange={() => alert("alert")} value={"x"}></math-field>`. I believe this to be due to the onChange prop being a react prop and not a prop of the actual html element, although I may be way off. All I want to do is set the onChange of the original html element. Such that in the actual html file the component will render to look like `<math-field onChange="myFunc" value="x"></math-field>` where `myFunc` is the function called when changed.

My code is essentially:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <math-field onChange={() => alert("hi")} value={"x"}></math-field>
    )
}

export default App
```

edit: I have imported the Mathlive library correctly in the base html file such that

```
<script defer src="//unpkg.com/mathlive"></script>
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but I can't find any mention of an `onchange` attribute in the [docs for this web component library](https://cortexjs.io/mathlive/).

Comment: in particular [this section](https://cortexjs.io/mathlive/guides/interacting/#listening-for-changes-to-a-mathfield) talks about listening for the `change` event, but as far as I can tell (I'm not very familiar with web components) you can't set handlers for this with `onXXX` attributes like you can with plain HTML, you have to use the `addEventListener` API (and to use it in React it will be best to use a `ref` to get a reference to the element/component).

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks! I misunderstood the docs. I ended up implementing an addEventListener solution which works fine